# Ractive.js & Datatables dynamic row expression

Tags: jquery, datatables, ractivejs

I'm trying to get a ractive on-click event working in a datatables "render" function:

```
 columns: [
                {
                    title: 'Aktion',
                    width: 120,
                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: false,
                    data: 'id',
                    render: function (data, table, row) {
                        return "<button class='btn btn-primary btn-xs edit-tarif' on-click='edit("+data+")'>edit</button>";
                    }
                },
```

but it will not be evaluated by the ractive.js's mustache compiler, because it's rendered after the initial load.

Is there a way to say "re-render" part of the dom and evaluate?
Currently i'm using a workaround with jQuery

```
$(document).on("click", 'button.edit-tarif', function () {...}
```

But i'd like to use the ractive function.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to get a ractive on-click event working in a datatables "render" function

Do it the other way around. Put your datatables code inside Ractive, specifically inside an `onrender`. The reason why `onrender` is because the component DOM is already rendered onto the page.

```
<div class="data-table-container"></div>

<script>
component.exports = {
  onrender: function(){
    var instance = this;

    // Make datatables render into data-table-container
    // Use this.find('.data-table-container') get the reference to the container
    // inside the component.
    render: function(data){
      instance.edit(data);
    }
  },
  edit: function(data){...}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of this? I'm new to ractive, and unsure how to implement your code.

This is what I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/j0mtx72f/

but it doesn't change the way the row is rendered.

Comment: your jsfiddle is incomplete...  the app init point `el: '#content'` is missing, you will need ```<div id="content"></div>``` on the page.